# Проблема с input type=date на маках

Tags: ios, input, mac

[image: некорректно отображается поле input type=date]

Есть форма, все поля во всех браузерах и ОС отображаются корректно, кроме поля с типом date. Оно почему-то вот так съезжает, причем только на маках, в винде все ок. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Дело совершенно не в MacOS.
Здесь все дело в браузере Safari.

Вот статья https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date
в которой говориться об этой особенности `<input type="date"/>`